# Truncating elements in certain order

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I have an container where I have multiple items that need to truncated in different order when resizing the window.
Here is codesandbox of it https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-farrell-jr9qlg?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=1504&resolutionHeight=675

If I have an starting container like this [image]

then is it possible to

1. truncate the text inside edit button so just the icons will stay
2. truncate the items
3. then truncate the remaining icons from edit btn is edit btn will be hidden
4. then the status so minimum 1 symbol is left
5. last one would be My btn where only one symbol + arrow icons are left.

For the My btn and status when truncation is happening there should be ..., but if its the minimum size which is 1 symbol then the dots are now shown.

This is the items and text of edit btn truncated

[image]

and this would be the final minimum size

[image]

I tried multiple approaches, but so far I can make only the items truncate, but I don't know how to do the edit btn and rest in order that I would wanna.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this via CSS or JavaScript? For CSS you'd use media queries, the downside being you'd kinda need to know the sizes of the elements beforehand. For JavaScript you'd be using a resize event handler, doing some math with the calculated sizes of the elements, and then either setting the element styles directly (pure JS solution), or setting pre-defined CSS classes on the container (mixed JS & CSS solution). I'd say the latter would be ideal based on what you want to achieve, but you didn't exactly specify how you want to achieve it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.